# Parity symmetry complete/detailed definition and the group elements

Tags: representation-theory, parity

I am trying to write down a complete/detailed definition for the parity symmetry. Symmetry as a concept is different in mathematics and in physics. There are also many other concepts which differ in their use in physics and mathematics i.e : symmetry group, discrete/continuous group, continuous and discrete symmetry etc.
I am trying to consider the following concepts and phrases for the definition:

1. Parity symmetry.
2. Parity transformation.
3. Invariant property (invariance and symmetry while similar they also differ in use)
4. parity symmetry group.
5. discrete symmetry group.

Then:

In physics:

"Parity symmetry it describes the invariance of a system, it's properties, under the parirty transformation, a spatial transformation, represented via the symmetry group of parity, a discrete symmetry group."

Is my definition, while including the above listed phrases accurate?

Also, can someone show me the fact that there is a group for parity? I.e elements, neutral element, inverse etc?

In other words, which are the elements and the operation in the symmetry group of parity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition is a good definition.  As for the exact group that is the symmetry group of parity, it is $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the group of order 2, because applying parity twice gets you back where you started.  The elements of this group are just the parity operation and the identity operation.

Comment: If we go by the mathematical definition of a group, a group has elements, an operation and the indenty element. In the Symmetry group of parity if parity you listed the elements, but what about the operation between them?

Comment: @imbAF A group is completely defined by the multiplication rule of its elements.  In this case, the identity times the parity operation gives you the parity operation, the identity times the identity gives the identity, and parity times parity gives identity.

Comment: But why multiplication and not some other operation? Is there a fundamental reason for that?

Comment: @imbAF You can call the operation whatever you want, it makes no difference.  The operation is fully defined by the two inputs and the one output.  But multiplication makes the most sense to call it because typically we end up representing group elements as matrices that act on vectors, with matrix multiplication as the representative of the group operation.